# Power Grid - Korea : How are resources purchased?

Tags: power-grid

**From the Power Grid - Korea map rules :**

> Phase 3 : Buying Resources
>
> In reverse player order, each player chooses one of the two markets
> from which he will buy resources this round. He must buy all resources
> for the round from the market he chooses. If the market chosen has no
> more of a resource he wants, he will not be able to buy that resource
> this round.

[Source : Power Grid Korea Rules](https://www.riograndegames.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Power-Grid-China-Korea-Rules.pdf)

**Questions**

Note : All of the following actions would be done in reverse turn order.

> **Case 1 :** Do all players choose, each in turn, a market and then, all players, again each in turn, buy their resources?
>
> **Case 2 :** Do all players choose a market and immediately buy their resources from that merket before the next player chooses a market and
> buys resources?

The reason for my question stems from the aformentioned rule :

> **If the market chosen has no more of a resource he wants, he will not be able to buy that resource this round.**

One has to admit that a reasonable player would not choose to buy from an empty market.

The only justification I can find for this rule is the following :

A non-empty market becomes empty after the player has selected it.

The only way for that to happen is that the previous player has bought all the remaining resources.

That could reasonably only happen in **Case 1**.

Comment: For starters, I think you mean "Case 1" in the last sentence. Now you have overlooked the whole point of the map/rule: players can't buy from both markets in a turn. So the prices - and availability - of all the resources you need force you into some tough choices.

Comment: Further, the imprecision of the "empty market" language isn't helping things. Very rarely will an *entire* market be depleted of every single resource. You're right that some players may not be able to source all of the resources they want at prices they can afford from both markets during a given round, but that's the tension. The only way someone could arrive at **Case 1** is by adding to the rules. On your turn, you buy all you want from one market. You can't buy from both. "Choosing a market" is equivalent to *buying from a market, knowing that you won't be allowed to buy from the other*

Comment: @The Chaz : You're absolutely right - I corrected the error at the end of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 2, as confirmed by the publisher.
https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2029922/korea-does-everyone-choose-their-market-anyone-buy